# Get single item from cURL plugin API call inside bash

Tags: wp-api, curl

I'm trying to get only the `last_updated` date from a plugin through an API call in a bash script.

I'm trying to use cURL but that's giving me some issues. On the browser I can get to to plugin like this:
[https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request[slug]=custom-comment-links](https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/?action=plugin_information&request%5Bslug%5D=custom-comment-links)

Looked over here but this seems more geared towards PHP:
https://dd32.id.au/projects/wordpressorg-plugin-information-api-docs/
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Plugins

Comment: Looks like I may need to exclude all of the fields I don't want, but still not working...
`curl -d 'action=plugin_information&request[slug]=custom-comment-links&fields[tested]=false' https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems the API is closed source and there may not be a way to get only a single option then the only other option is parsing the response.

I hear jq is the way to go for parsing JSON within the shell, but I don't want to add dependencies and grep seems to have done the job:
`curl -v -d 'action=plugin_information&request[slug]=custom-comment-links' https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/ --stderr - | grep -o '"last_updated":"[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$'`

You can replace `last_updated` with anything you'd like :)